# Globalise3 with fallbacks but w/o prefilling form with fallback translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, globalization, formtastic

With

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = { :fr => :en }
```

and

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
end
```

and

```
I18n.local = :en
```

and

```
Thing.create! :name => 'broken'
```

is there anyway of preventing Globalize3 from returning 'broken' for name when the locale is set to :fr?

I want fallbacks, but I don't want my French form to be prepopulated with the English translation.

I don't want a multi-locale form. I don't want to prefix every attribute name with _en. I just want to tell globalize to return a blank translation.

I'd hoped

```
thing(:fr)
```

or something similar would exist.

I've tried all sorts of hackery - trying to temporarily disable fallbacks whilst the form is populated etc. I could write the form myself (I'm using Formtastic) or nest the translation but it feels like I'm missing something.

Forgive me if I've failed to convey but it 5:30am.

Anyone have any pointers?

---

#### Update

It looks like Globalize3 automatically builds a translation for the current locale if it doesn't exist. As the values for each are nil they fallback. If I loop through them and set them all to an empty string before my form accesses them I get the desired affect.

I'm using inherited resources hence my model instance is called resource. I put this in a helper and run it before the form is populated:

```
if resource.respond_to?(:translations) && request[:action] == 'edit'
  resource.translated_attribute_names.each do |attribute_name|
    resource[attribute_name] = '' unless resource.translation[attribute_name].present?
  end
end
```

Feels like I'm fighting the gem or missing a trick.

Comment: Although it's not a duplicate you may find useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798158/how-to-avoid-globalize3-from-returning-fallback-translations-for-an-attribute-in/19932970#19932970